# The compile file doesn´t seem to be working

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I wanted to ask if the following Makefile is correctly written, because the programme doesn´t seem to compile correctly but I´m not sure if the makefile or the code is the problem :

```
CC = /usr/bin/gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pthread 
DEPS = config.h shmHandling.h gameboard.h thinker.h strTools.h performConnection.h main.h
OBJ = main.o config.o shmHandling.o gameboard.o thinker.o strTools.o performConnection.o

# Link all .o files to program
%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    @echo "-----------------------"
    @echo "Linking object files"
    $(CC) -o -c $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

sysprak-client: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

# Compile everything and run it with CL params
.PHONY: play
play: sysprak-client
    @echo "-----------------------"
    @echo "Launching sysprak-client with GameID: $(GAME_ID)"
    ./sysprak-client -g $(GAME_ID) -p $(PLAYER)


.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -rm *.o $(OBJ)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is displayed on the screen when you run make?

Comment: I get a lot of erros, but the code seems to be working on another computer without the make file                                   % make            
/usr/bin/gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pthread    -c -o gameboard.o gameboard.c
gameboard.c: In function 'isEmpty':
gameboard.c:7:8: error: 'DEBUGL' undeclared (first use in this

Comment: Every error is associated with the gameboard file

Comment: Where do you declare `DEBUGL`?

Comment: If you run make, all commands are printed. You can check and try each of these commands manually to find out where your error is.

Answer (score 1):

This recipe:

```
$(CC) -o -c $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

shall be:

```
$(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)
```

The `-o` option must be followed by the output file name and `$@` expands exactly as the name of the target object file. So `-o $@` is correct while `-o -c` is not.

Note: the comment before the rule it is part of is wrong. The rule compiles the C source files to object files. It is the following rule that *Link all .o files to program*. Same with the `echo` command. You should probably rewrite all this as:

```
# Compile each .c to .o
%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    @echo "-----------------------"
    @echo "Compiling $<"
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

# Link all .o files to program
sysprak-client: $(OBJ)
    @echo "Linking object files"
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

# Run with CL params
.PHONY: play
play: sysprak-client
    @echo "-----------------------"
    @echo "Launching sysprak-client with GameID: $(GAME_ID)"
    ./sysprak-client -g $(GAME_ID) -p $(PLAYER)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input firstly. I used what you told me but I still get the same error. I just looked at the directory and I get all the Header Files as executables (For example: thinker.h.gch or performconnection.h.gch). Is that the problem? Because I thought that the header files weren´t supossed to become the executables

Comment: @computersciencegermany The `.h.gch` files are pre-compiled header files. If you have the corresponding header files (`.h`) simply delete the `.h.gch` files. If not, well, you are in trouble because there is probably something wrong with the pre-compiled versions and there is not much you can do about it. What's wrong can be that one of your `.c` source files tries to include more than one, or that the compilation options you use are not the same as the ones used for pre-compilation, or something else...